# How to send container to detach mode which require tty at the beginning of the process?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tty

my Dockerfile contain excutable script and their corresponding flag as CMD instruction. If i start docker container using docker run -d then my excutable script get terminated. If i start docker container using docker run -it then container will keep running. Now if i want to quit terminal i can do **ctr** and **pq** it will move container in detach mode. I want to automate the docker build and deploy process. In automation script i can't manually press **ctr** and **pq**. How to acheive this ??

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example which illustrates your problem?

Comment: Please include the dockerfile too.

Comment: @Paolo if i start my container using docker run -d -p 4000:4000 <image-name> then my docker container get terminated. if i start my docker container using docker run -it -p 4000:4000 <image-name> then it will keep running. If i want to close the terminal and keep container running then i press ctr + pq.